# Windows 10 - 3 separate machines showing Account Unknown S-1-5-21-*-*-1000

Tags: windows-10

I have just noticed, that every program in

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs

has following account listed under Security tab

> Account Unknown S-1-5-21-*-*-1000

This account has only Special permissions, i have checked my main Windows 10 machine, my Windows 10 laptop, all have latest versions and everything updated. My friend has Windows 10 too and has the same issue, only with different SID. We both have Kaspersky antivirus, if that might be the reason.

Also, i only use only one account, there is no other account and never was, the same applies for my friend. No domains, no AD.

What this could be?

I have also ran

> wmic useraccount get name,sid

and got result back, my user account has exactly the same SID except the end, there is not -**1000**, but -**1001**.

In registry, HKEY_USERS, i have found only 2 s-1-5-21 entries. Both same, but one ends with _**classes**. These entries have identical SID as my account - ending with -**1001**, so it's my account. However i do not know, why there is an unknown account with -**1000** ending.

Comment: If the SID does not exist on [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab) page then it's not a built-in account.  Which means a user was created either by an installation and then the user was deleted or the user was created an then deleted.  Is there a reason you masked the SID?  The real value can't be used to identify you and makes it harder for anyone to perform research.  Was this system upgraded from a previous version of Windows?  Please, edit your question, do not submit a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The number seems to be random, so that's why i did not include it. It's different on my PC, on my laptop and on friend's pc. It differs from the SID my user account has only in the end - instead of 1001, it ends with 1000.

Comment: Local accounts are incremented.  So it ending in 1000 or 1001 simply means an existing user was created and their SID ends in 1000 instead.  Were these systems running a previous version of Windows by chance and upgraded to Windows 10?

Comment: No, it is also weird, that my main account, the one which was created when reinstalling the computer has got 1001 RID (ending SID), which is weird, because there is unknown account, which has 1000. It increments, as you said. The same applies for my friend.

Comment: I've also contacted another friend and he has the same issue.

Comment: Do these machines have AMD or Nvidia GPU. I know when the Nvidia Experience is installed a user is created.  Honestly, since we know the SID is a local account, and if you only have local accounts with known SIDs then removing an unknown SID from the ACL isn't a big deal.

Comment: That might be it! All of us have Nvidia GPU. I was worried a bit that it might be something malicious. However, i am extremely cautious about such things. And the fact that it is on my pc, friend's almost clean pc, my almost new laptop with very few programs confirms that.

Comment: I will do some research once I am in front of a machine with a Nvidia card.

Comment: Alright. Let me know and thank you.

Comment: I have done some research on my end and i have found out that this Unknown account is most certainly defaultuser0. When you check C:\Users and check properties of defaultuser0 folder, you will find that in security tab, the same Unknown account - SID has permissions.

Answer (score 0):

That account does not show up on my machines, so it is by no means on every machine.

Open Control Panel, System, and then in the Window that results, Advanced System Settings. Click on the Profiles button in the Advanced tab and that User Profile should show up.

Kaspersky is a decent guess. On Windows 10, I use and my clients use, Windows Defender as it is top rated.

I suggest you leave the user alone as removing it may have consequences you do not want.